# Is there an URL to create safes and execute transaction on Mumbai from Gnosis Safe Transaction Service API?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I have an API to deploy a safe, as well as to start a transaction, confirm it and execute the transaction. The API is built using Typescript, Node, and integrates the Safe Core SDK and the Gnosis Safe Transaction Service API. Everything is running smoothly at Rinkeby. But the solution needs to run on Polygon, of course while we are in the development and testing phase, it needs to run in Mumbai. But I can't find anywhere the specification of the URL that allows me to access the Safe contracts in Mumbai. The documentation says that there are only these services: https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/backend/available-services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The documentation says that there are only these services: https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/backend/available-services

The documentation doesn't lie. There is no UI/APIs deployed for Mumbai testnet